How to fail GitHub Actions running on windows-latest based on the output of a python script?
I have the following GitHub Actions Workflow:
name: Workflow
on: [push]

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  workflow:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          ...

      - name: Run code
        id: exit_code
        run: |
          $result = python test/test_1.py
          echo "my_output=$result" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      - name: Check Output and Fail if Not Equal to 0
        run: |
          output_value="${{ steps.exit_code.outputs.my_output }}"
          if [[ "$output_value" != "0" ]]; then
            echo "Output value is not 0. Failing the action."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Output value is 0. Continuing with the action."
          fi

The  script runs as expected and I would like to save its output inside GitHub actions so that I can check it in the last step. The script returns an int with the output_value between 0 and 4. I would like to fail the workflow if the output_value != 0.
After looking at similar questions I came to the if check above, but for me it throws this error:
Run if [ "" -ne 0 ]; then
ParserError: D:\a\_temp\name.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  if [ "" -ne 0 ]; then
     |    ~
     | Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.

It seems even saving the output from my script didn't work as it is just an empty string. Here is how the python file looks:
...

def test():
    ...

    return exit_code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit_code_final = test()
    print(exit_code_final)


Add shell: bash for that run section where you're using Bash syntax. The default shell on Windows runners is Powershell hence the error.

@Azeem thank you, that step seems to work now. I still have the problem that the python output is not saved as it should. Instead of the number between 0 and 4, I get "". You can give an answer instead of a comment, so I can choose your answer as correct.

I got a solution in another post. You can still post your answer about using shell:bash, so I can select it.

Good to hear that. I already marked this for closure due to a typo. All the best!
